# sorted-map throws exception on failed key look-up

Tags: exception, dictionary, clojure, dynamic-typing

```
user=> (def m (sorted-map 1 2))
#'user/m
user=> (map? m)
true
user=> (get m :type)
ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Keyword
  clojure.lang.Keyword.compareTo (Keyword.java:114)
```

It appears that `sorted-map` has chosen a numerical comparison function, which won't compare with a keyword.

It would be nice to reason, "This thing supports IPersistentMap. So, I can call `get` on it to find out if it's a kind of map that I know about without risk of throwing an exception." The docstring for `get` says "Returns the value mapped to key, not-found or nil if key not present."

Is throwing an exception on key look-up a bug? More importantly, is there a safe, standard way to check if an arbitrary object is of a given "type" (defined by the value associated with its `:type` key)?

Comment: sorted-map produces a TreeMap with sorted with sorted keys. To find a specifec key it should compare existing keys with your requested one, and here's where it fails: `(< 1 :asd)`.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem reasonable that keys to a `sorted-map` should be comparable in some way, which is not the case with `1` and `:type`, this is the cause of your exception.

Having said that I'd argue that you should be able to query a map with a key of any type and get `nil` if the supplied key and keys in the map are not comparable.

You can solve the problem by supplying your own comparator via `sorted-map-by` that does the required type checking.

Comment: My main concern is that I can write a little function that tests if any object has a "type" of interest—say, by seeing if it's a `map?` and then querying for its `:type` key. Would the `sorted-map-by` approach require me to never make a plain `sorted-map` nor accept one from a library function?

Answer (score 0):

this is a thought-provoking question, i'm glad you asked it. after pondering, I would tend expect the same as was mentioned in the other answer -- i'd probably like a `nil` to be returned, but maybe Rich has a philosophical reason for doing it this way instead.

as for the last part of your question: you can use `type`. you can also use `instance?` if you want to test for a known type. i guess the trick is the type is (almost always i believe) going to be the underlying Java class

```
user=> (type foo)
clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap

user=> (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentTreeMap foo)
true
```

***Edit:*** per discussion below, I'm putting some additional example code here (easier to read than in comments). this will allow arbitrary metadata to be attached to the data structure:

```
user=> (def foo (sorted-map 1 2))
#'user/foo
user=> (def foo-enhanced (with-meta foo {:type :integer-keys}))
#'user/foo-enhanced
user=> foo-enhanced
{1 2}
user=> (meta foo-enhanced)
{:type :integer-keys}
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in the question: I meant "type" in a broad sense, where two different maps have different "types" if you have different conventions or expectations for what keys and values go into them. People often represent those expectations with a `:type` key. I ran into the problem that led to this question when I wrote some debugging code to print arguments but [only if they're not a certain huge map](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36722077/1393162) that represents the entire state of the system. Other maps are fine, though. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: without more context it's hard to say too much, but one thing you might look at is `meta` and `with-meta`. that might actually be a safer way to go. i'll put an example above.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of using `meta`. I'll think about this.

Comment: Hmm, after thinking about it a bit, I don't think `meta` will work. It requires that all code follow a certain convention. I'm just looking for a way to just tell, regardless of whether a certain convention has been followed, if an object is a map containing a `:type` key with a certain value. (My current workaround is just to enclose the call to `get` inside a `try` block that catches *all* exceptions. I hope there's a better way!)