# Why can't you RSeq an RSeq?

Tags: clojure, sequence, reverse

```
user=> (rseq [:a :b])
(:b :a)
user=> (rseq (rseq [:a :b]))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.APersistentVector$RSeq cannot be cast to
  clojure.lang.Reversible  clojure.core/rseq (core.clj:1532)
```

Why can't `rseq` accept the result of a previous call to `rseq`?

I read in the docstring that the argument has to be (actually, "can be") a vector or sorted-map, and the above shows that it can't be an `RSeq`, so I already know that. What I want to know is: is there a good reason for this restriction? Is it just an oversight, or does this restriction provide some important benefit?

Also, is there a convenient workaround for this, other than just never calling `rseq`? It's hard to know, when you return an `RSeq` from one function, whether some other function somewhere else might call `rseq` on it.

I'm asking because it's frustrating to see my code throw exceptions for [such surprising reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37410580/1393162). If I knew why this made sense, I might be less likely to make this and similar kinds of errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call `rseq` on a seq, since you need an input collection with constant-time random access to fullfill `rseq`'s constant-time performance characteristics, and seqs only provide efficient access (iteration) from the head down.

Calling `rseq` on the result of `rseq` cannot be special-cased to return the original collection since the original collection is never a seq. And if calling `rseq` on a RSeq would return something `(seq coll)`, that won't make it straightforward to support `(rseq (drop x (rseq coll)))`. It's probably those kinds of complications that kept the language implementers from supporting "recursive" rseq at all.

If you need a general reversal function, use `reverse` - which will be slower. If you can, you probably just want to keep a reference to `(seq coll)` and `(rseq coll)` if you need both.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that an `RSeq` (the object returned by `rseq`) could easily be reversed in constant time, just by unwrapping the `RSeq`, but I think you've nailed it: a vector is not a seq. I'm still new to Clojure, and I'm still frequently misreading "returns a seq" as "returns something sequential, like a vector" and not "returns something like an iterator".

Answer (score 3):

Because `rseq` works only for the special reversible sequences. But the result of its application is an ordinary seq. You can always check if you can `rseq` a sequence with a `reversible?` predicate:

```
(defn reverse* [s]
  (if (reversible? s)
    (rseq s)
    (reverse s)))
```

Why this fallback isn't in `rseq` (or `reverse`) function itself? The reason is that `rseq` should guarantee its execution time predictability, I guess.

If you really need to reverse the collection back later, you would better keep it as a vector for example: `(rseq (vec (rseq [1 2 3])))`

Comment: So, is it common practice, or at least wise practice, to only call `rseq` to make something that you're going to use in code that you know thoroughly? I'm wondering if I should think of `rseq` as a "dangerous" function, as in "Well, when you called `rseq`, you were practically asking for a run-time exception."

Comment: well if you look at it from the angle of an "protocol" (some set of functions can only be applied to some types of collections) everything becomes clean, like: `assoc` or `update` can only be called with `Associative`, `rseq` could only be called with `Reversible` and so on. So yes, you should remember that in your code, and double check types of values returned by external libs.

Comment: To answer your question about common practice, In the last six years working Clojure as my day job I have not seen any calls to rseq.